# Rails 3: Bundle install fails on Nokogiri gem, says libxml2

Tags: windows, rubygems, nokogiri, bundler, libxml2

Hi I'm trying to get a dev environment setup on my windows machine. I've installed rubygems via cygwin. When I run bundle install I get an error on installing the nokogiri gem. It says I'm missing libxml2.

When I go to the nokogiri website they say "gem install nokogiri" should do everything I need for windows. However, running that just gives me the same error as bundle install.

```
Installing nokogiri (1.4.4) with native extensions /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/r
ubygems/installer.rb:543:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem nativ
e extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

        /usr/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for libxml/parser.h... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokog
iri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
$
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
        --with-zlib-dir
        --without-zlib-dir
        --with-zlib-include
        --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
        --with-zlib-lib
        --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
        --with-iconv-dir
        --without-iconv-dir
        --with-iconv-include
        --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
        --with-iconv-lib
        --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
        --with-xml2-dir
        --without-xml2-dir
        --with-xml2-include
        --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
        --with-xml2-lib
        --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
        --with-xslt-dir
        --without-xslt-dir
        --with-xslt-include
        --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
        --with-xslt-lib
        --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4 fo
r inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4/ext/nokogiri/gem_ma
ke.out
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:496:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:496:in `build_ext
ensions'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:177:in `install'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/source.rb:10
1:in `install'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/rubygems_int
egration.rb:279:in `preserve_paths'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/source.rb:91
:in `install'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/installer.rb
:58:in `run'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/rubygems_int
egration.rb:93:in `with_build_args'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/installer.rb
:57:in `run'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:
12:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:
12:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/installer.rb
:49:in `run'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/installer.rb
:8:in `install'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/cli.rb:270:i
n `update'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/
task.rb:22:in `send'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/
task.rb:22:in `run'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/
invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.
rb:246:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/
base.rb:389:in `start'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/bin/bundle:13
        from /usr/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
        from /usr/bin/bundle:19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error on Ubuntu 11.04 and solved it by installing the `libxml2-dev` package.

Answer (score 1):

If installing the `liblxml12-dev` package it doesn't fix, try installing `libxslt-dev` too. It solved my problem (http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html)